# Find the minimun of $\int_0^{t_1} \frac{1 + \dot{x(t)}^2}{x(t)} dt, x(0) = 0, x(t_1) = x_1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

> Find the minimun of $\int_0^{t_1} \frac{1 + \dot{x(t)}^2}{x(t)} dt, x(0) = 0, x(t_1) = x_1$

**My attempt**

We have:
$$L(x,\dot{x}) = \frac{1 + \dot{x}^2}{x}$$

and

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = \frac{1 + \dot{x}^2}{-x^2}, \quad \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} = 2\frac{\dot{x}}{x}, \quad \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} = 2\frac{\ddot{x}}{x}$$

From Euler-Lagrange equation:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} - \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} = 0 \iff 1 + \dot{x}^2 + 2x\ddot{x} = 0$$

I couldn't solve this ODE.

The book says that the answer for this question is $x(t) = Kt^2 - t, K = \frac{x_1 - t_1}{t_1^2}$

How could solve that ODE?

Comment: That solution does not solve the ODE you gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = \frac{1 + \dot{x}^2}{-x^2}$$
Correct.
$$\quad \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} = 2\frac{\dot{x}}{x}$$
Correct
$$\quad \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} = 2\frac{\ddot{x}}{x}$$
NOT correct. You have to use the quotient rule, since $x$ depends on $t$ also, so that
$$\quad \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} = 2\frac{x\ddot{x}-\dot{x}^2}{x^2}$$